# "Bad" or "Poor" is more severe?

Tags: meaning

Saw this [thread](http://forums.digitalspy.co.uk/showthread.php?t=1922762&page=3).
[image]

In the thread, **poor** is implied in a sense that it is more severe than **bad**. I myself would choose to replace **poor** with **terrible**. But I don't see anything implying that in dictionaries. Is that always the case—**poor** is worse than **bad**—if the two words are used under the same context?

Comment: I agree with you that the order used here is poor or even bad.

Comment: This is terrible word choice on the part of pollsters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [About quality - "low", "bad" and "poor"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184483/about-quality-low-bad-and-poor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the list clearly is meant to be in order of quality, and that one is meant to infer that **poor** is worse than **bad**. Given the common usage for these two words, I don't see that they have any clear ordering between them, so the inclusion of both of them in an ordered list of this type seems a *bad* (or *poor*) choice as it can lead to ambiguous interpretation.

If anything, one might think that **poor** was less severe. **Poor**, in addition to being used to describe quality, also describes persons who are in a state of poverty. *Poor* people can also be *good* and worthy of praise and sympathy, whereas *bad* people are always just *bad*.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing is implied. No need to draw inappropriate inferences.

The list is **not** entirely in the order of quality.

In this context, *poor* does mean 'poor' as usual. It is not intended to mean 'worse than bad' at all.

Sometimes, for statistical or other reasons, certain heads need to be placed separately at the bottom of the list, and that's what is happening here. Think *NOTA* ('None of the Above'), it's a rather different case, but it's similarly *always* the last in the list.