# Scale of Rarity Adjectives

Tags: synonyms

What is the general scale for rarity adjectives? On a scale of 1 to 10, with 1 being 'abundant' and 10 being 'extremely scarce', what adjectives could be used to describe the areas in between? For example, what would a two be?

Comment: I doubt any pair of users here could agree on a single "unambiguously-correct" list of such terms. It's all a matter of opinion.

Comment: I don't think it's impossible in principle to give an evidence-based (rather than opinion-based) answer to this question. Compare [What is worse than “mediocre”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299005)

Answer (score 3):

As has been said in a comment, no two users will place these adjectives exactly in the same position. Then again, their positions can't be very different from this:

> 1. omnipresent
> 2. abundant
> 3. frequent
> 4. common
> 5. occasional
> 6. uncommon
> 7. sporadic
> 8. rare
> 9. unique
> 10. nonexistent

Comment: I might add *unique* or *singular* or similar in there between 9 and 10, and if 10 is "nonexistent" then maybe 1 (or 0?) should be something like *ubiquitous* or *pervasive* or *omnipresent*? (I would tell you +1, but this seems to be +2.)

Comment: @1006a   Good suggestions.

Comment: #10 can't be "non-existent" - how can you classify something that doesn't exist?