# What word do we use to say that something is so easily available or commonly prevalent?

Tags: single-word-requests, common-word

If I have to say that:

> "potatoes are so commonly available in that place that every random shop you visit has a store of them as if its their staple food."

Or if I have to say:

> "it is so cold over there that rum is so easily available or commonly seen or prevalent everywhere inorder to withstand the cold."

Is there any single word or phrase or a better way to convey **that something is very commonly available or seen almost everywhere or easily prevailing** ?

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): [scale of rarity adjectives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384516/scale-of-rarity-adjectives/384520#384520)

Answer (score 54):

**[Ubiquitous](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/ubiquitous)**:

> *adjective*
>
> present, or seeming to be present, everywhere at the same time; omnipresent

Comment: The noun form is "ubiquity" by the way, as in "The ubiquity of potatoes makes them a staple food for that culture".

Comment: Please provide a link to your quotation, otherwise, despite its popularity, your answer may be deleted as a "Low Quality Post". And don't respond to me — I'm only the messenger.

Answer (score 21):

**Commonplace** seems a good fit.

> *commonplace* adjective
>
> ​ happening often or often seen or experienced and so not considered
>   to be special:
>
> *Electric cars are increasingly commonplace.*

[[CED](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/commonplace)]

synonyms include *widespread, prevalent* [[Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/commonplace)]

Comment: Please consider your “answer”, and perhaps this question itself, in light of this post from one of Stack Exchange’s Community Managers (an employee) on [Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160/2085). You might also consider our Help Center’s directions on [how to reference material written by others](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) in posts that should be mainly your own words rather than copypasta.

Comment: @tchrist I'm very willing to delete this answer. As you know, I rarely give simplistic answers anywhere other than 'comments'; I judged this to be borderline. But if you're going to be consistent across the site, you should be removing, not just recommending for deletion, a good many questions and answers. Ask me to delete and I will. / There seems little more to say in this 'answer'. This is true with many if not most SWRs.

Answer (score 14):

I would suggest *abundant*.

> existing or available in large quantities; plentiful.

As you can see, the definition from [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abundant) shows that *abundant* encompasses what you want to say in one word. It is applicable to "things" like potatoes and gives the impression that they are found everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is ***omnipresent***:

> ***[omnipresent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/omnipresent)***
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1. Widely or constantly encountered; widespread.
>      *‘the omnipresent threat of natural disasters’*

The noun form would be [omnipresence](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/omnipresence).

Of course, ***[widespread](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/widespread)*** (from the definition) might work as well.  (Though I'm not sure what the noun form of that would be.)

Comment: Not exactly wrong, but omnipresent is more often used for abstractions than objects like potatoes. "The omnipresent religious influence..." "Omnipresent fears of a stock market crash" etc

Comment: Omnipresent potatos would make sense if you were expl-ining their presence in every dish in a cuisine, though that's approaching potato as concept i suppose.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "[readily](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/readily) available" comes to mind.

I had an example I was going to write, but then I said the words too many times in my head and now it sounds wrong. :(

Comment: About semantic satiation - don't worry. Just cite some examples from the net. [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/readily) usually provides a selection to accompany its entries.

Answer (score 1):

The previously provided Ubiquitous is the best general answer, but in some cases you may want to imply that a thing is not only commonplace, but can't be avoided, to the extent that it becomes humorous or even annoying.

In this case you could say that the thing is [obligatory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/obligatory). This is often used to indicate that the item's presence is so strong that it's almost as if it were required by law.

"As we dined while traveled through the region, the obligatory potatoes began to pall..."
"the obligatory XKCD comic..."

Comment: Can't be avoided = unavoidable. Synonyms: inescapable, inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

For non-food items, you can use "[ten a penny](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-two-ten-a-penny)" in British English, or its US English equivalent "a dime a dozen" to indicate that something is readily, and cheaply available.

> be two/ten a penny UK (US be a dime a dozen)
>
> :  to be very common

​

Answer (score 1):

[Glut](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/glut), as defined by Lexico:

> 1. an excessively abundant supply of something.
>    "there is a glut of cars on the market"
>    synonyms:   surplus, excess, surfeit, superfluity, overabundance, superabundance, oversupply, plethora
>    "a glut of cars"

Answer (score 0):

If the subject is extremely common, "[like water](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like%20water)" fits:

> informal
>      :  in large amounts -  He spends money *like water*.

So, in the context of your examples, "potatoes are like water in that place" and "it's so cold over there, rum flows like water" (or "...they drink rum like water").

Comment: I think this is only for specific things (such as drinks) rather than everything.  'Potatoes are like water' doesn't immediately conjure images of plentiful supply, rather really unappealing potatoes.

Comment: This fits for basically everything you can consume.